# CSS vertical align objects :before

Tags: css, wordpress, vertical-alignment

On my website www.drivkrets.se I´m trying to insert a symbol (orange lines) before my headings using CSS :before. I´have been able to insert the image in the right size but now I would like to vertical align the symbol image with the text. When the heading is on one line or three lines I doesn´t look good. I´ve tried different variations of code but none of them works.

Does anyone have any idea how I should do this?

The headings that suppose to have this symbol before I´ve named ".specialrubrik". Now I´m using the code:

```
.specialrubrik:before { 
content:url('http://www.drivkrets.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/orange-     
 marker-e1490098005864.png');
float: left;
margin-right: 12px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}
```

Best regards
Peter

Comment: Welcome Peter. When you can, it's best to create a small working example in jsFiddle or something like it. It's also important to include the associated markup, and to leave out things that aren't important. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS question and has nothing to do with WordPress. You don't want to float `inline-block` elements, and `vertical-align` only works with `display: inline-block` elements.

```css
.example-heading:before {
  display: inline-block; /* no floats! 'middle' only works with inline-block */
  content:url('http://www.drivkrets.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/orange-marker-e1490098005864.png');
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='example-heading'>Example heading</h2>
```

Comment: @hungerstar - I don't think your edit was valuable. I was trying to show the OP how a jsFiddle works on purpose. Moving back the explicit content URL (that will likely not exist in a week) also removes my point that the OP should use simplified versions when asking the question. I think you've wasted your time and made this answer much less useful to the OP and to everyone else.

Comment: I can see your point on the `content` URL and will be happy to change that, but completely disagree on the other points. If one can create a simplified version of their problem with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), why create it offsite? All the code is easily visible and demonstrates the solution to the OP and future visitors on SO. Nobody needs to leave the site, and much like your expiry concern for the URL the same could be argued for a 3rd party site like JSFiddle, CodePen etc.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that those 3rd party sites will be around in the future and valuable insight (code) may be lost. Containing a working example on SO is in everyone's benefit. There are times that third party sites provide capabilities currently beyond that of [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) and would be appropriate, though in this instance it is not. My edit provided a working example on SO, one less step to see how something works is a win.

Comment: I see your point, but learning how to build a targeted sample of the problem was the teachable moment here. Creating a 'stack snippet' has a higher barrier for your average person. Agree to disagree. The OP will likely continue to create less than wonderful posts because of you.

Comment: How is a Stack Snippet a higher barrier than a JSFiddle or CodePen? They'r the same type of resource. The OP has to do the same thing for a Stack Snippet as they would a JSFiddle - add HTML, CSS, JS and maybe some external libraries to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Top SO contributors are making the same edit all the time. Even you said, _"create a small working example in jsFiddle **or something like it**."_ Well, a Stack Snippet is something like it. Providing a Stack Snippet or a JSFiddle in an answer is the same difference.

Comment: I just don't find them useful. I can't fork them, I can't add to them easily. There are important questions on SO that help many people and are very specific. Then there are questions like these that might help 5 people. I just think you are wasting your time. We can agree to disagree. Get those points!

Comment: Yeah, I guess 30 seconds for an on site working example is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your idea @sheriffderek. I still don´t get it right.
I´ve changed the code now and trying to use the :before on h2 instead.

```
h2:before { 
content:url('http://www.drivkrets.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/orange-     
marker-e1490098005864.png');
margin-right: 12px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

h2 { 
text-align: left;
display: -webkit-inline-box;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It works when I have a short heading but if the heading is two or three rows it looks strange. Example: "Kunskap och uppfinningsrikedom till era elsystem". Do you know how I can make all of the text to flow right of the symbol?

Peter

Comment: I'd a jsFiddle with a few different examples for you to play with, but @hungerstart might just edit it out. I'll just paste it here: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/sgjwmhpz/1/ Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, great! Thanks a million, now it works like I want to.